# How the Saturated Pixels violate the assumption that the image formation process in linear?

Tags: image-processing

I am working in digital image restoration field and i have studied this is many research papers that presence of **saturated pixels** violates the assumption which is initially assumed by many **blind deconvolution algorithms**, that the image formation process is linear...

Can anyone please explain that how this rule is violated.?

Answer (score 2):

Blind deconvolution assumes that the blurred image is the result of distorting the original image by convolution. Convolution is a linear process, i.e. the image is just a sum of shifted and scaled versions of the original image. Pixel saturation, on the other hand, is a non-linear process, which cannot be modeled by convolution. Consequently, it cannot be handled by conventional blind deconvolution techniques. Also note that saturation is irreversible, i.e. once a quantity is saturated its original value cannot be recovered.

Comment: @MayankTiwari If this answered your question, then you should mark it as accepted.